# How to organize data of several datasets into the same dataframe using pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multi-index

I am having trouble in keeping some data organized as I want in a data frame using pandas in Python.

I would like to have a single data frame where the data would be organized in three columns (e.g. `Time`, `V` and `I`).

However, I would like to have the data of different samples in the same data frame so that I could easily select the data from `Sample#1` or `Sample#2`.

What I came up to was something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.arange(0,10,0.5), 'V': np.random.rand(20), 'I': np.random.rand(20)})
df1['Sample']= 'sample_1'

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.arange(0,10,0.5), 'V': np.random.rand(20), 'I': np.random.rand(20)})
df2['Sample']= 'sample_2'

df = df1.append(df2)
```

Notice that I added another columns called `Sample` to keep track of which data corresponds to which sample.

But  then I don't know how to call the data from `sample_1` or `sample_2` from df

How can I do this and is this the right way to organize my data? Should I be using `MultiIndex`?

Comment: I'd use your option and then choose the sample with `df.loc[df["Sample"] == "sample_1",:]`. It's more standard and having clean data is important (http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `MultiIndex` is one possible solution:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.arange(0,10,0.5), 
                    'V': np.random.rand(20), 
                    'I': np.random.rand(20)})

np.random.seed(2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': np.arange(0,10,0.5), 
                    'V': np.random.rand(20), 
                    'I': np.random.rand(20)})

#print (df1)
#print (df2)
```

You can [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all `DataFrame`s to one and in parameter `keys` specify each source `DataFrame`:

```
print (pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=('sample_1','sample_2')))
                    I  Time         V
sample_1 0   0.800745   0.0  0.417022
         1   0.968262   0.5  0.720324
         2   0.313424   1.0  0.000114
         3   0.692323   1.5  0.302333
         4   0.876389   2.0  0.146756
         5   0.894607   2.5  0.092339
         6   0.085044   3.0  0.186260
         7   0.039055   3.5  0.345561
         8   0.169830   4.0  0.396767
         9   0.878143   4.5  0.538817
         10  0.098347   5.0  0.419195
         11  0.421108   5.5  0.685220
         12  0.957890   6.0  0.204452
         13  0.533165   6.5  0.878117
         14  0.691877   7.0  0.027388
         15  0.315516   7.5  0.670468
         16  0.686501   8.0  0.417305
         17  0.834626   8.5  0.558690
         18  0.018288   9.0  0.140387
         19  0.750144   9.5  0.198101
sample_2 0   0.505246   0.0  0.435995
         1   0.065287   0.5  0.025926
         2   0.428122   1.0  0.549662
         3   0.096531   1.5  0.435322
         4   0.127160   2.0  0.420368
         5   0.596745   2.5  0.330335
         6   0.226012   3.0  0.204649
         7   0.106946   3.5  0.619271
         8   0.220306   4.0  0.299655
         9   0.349826   4.5  0.266827
         10  0.467787   5.0  0.621134
         11  0.201743   5.5  0.529142
         12  0.640407   6.0  0.134580
         13  0.483070   6.5  0.513578
         14  0.505237   7.0  0.184440
         15  0.386893   7.5  0.785335
         16  0.793637   8.0  0.853975
         17  0.580004   8.5  0.494237
         18  0.162299   9.0  0.846561
         19  0.700752   9.5  0.079645
```

Select data is possible by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) - see [cross section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#cross-section):

```
print (df.xs('sample_1', level=0))
           I  Time         V
0   0.800745   0.0  0.417022
1   0.968262   0.5  0.720324
2   0.313424   1.0  0.000114
3   0.692323   1.5  0.302333
4   0.876389   2.0  0.146756
5   0.894607   2.5  0.092339
6   0.085044   3.0  0.186260
7   0.039055   3.5  0.345561
8   0.169830   4.0  0.396767
9   0.878143   4.5  0.538817
10  0.098347   5.0  0.419195
11  0.421108   5.5  0.685220
12  0.957890   6.0  0.204452
13  0.533165   6.5  0.878117
14  0.691877   7.0  0.027388
15  0.315516   7.5  0.670468
16  0.686501   8.0  0.417305
17  0.834626   8.5  0.558690
18  0.018288   9.0  0.140387
19  0.750144   9.5  0.198101
```

If need select only some columns:

```
print (df.xs('sample_1', level=0)[['Time','I']])
    Time         I
0    0.0  0.800745
1    0.5  0.968262
2    1.0  0.313424
3    1.5  0.692323
4    2.0  0.876389
5    2.5  0.894607
6    3.0  0.085044
7    3.5  0.039055
8    4.0  0.169830
9    4.5  0.878143
10   5.0  0.098347
11   5.5  0.421108
12   6.0  0.957890
13   6.5  0.533165
14   7.0  0.691877
15   7.5  0.315516
16   8.0  0.686501
17   8.5  0.834626
18   9.0  0.018288
19   9.5  0.750144
```

---

Another solution is use `IndexSlice` - see [using slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['sample_1',:], ['Time','I']])
             Time         I
sample_1 0    0.0  0.800745
         1    0.5  0.968262
         2    1.0  0.313424
         3    1.5  0.692323
         4    2.0  0.876389
         5    2.5  0.894607
         6    3.0  0.085044
         7    3.5  0.039055
         8    4.0  0.169830
         9    4.5  0.878143
         10   5.0  0.098347
         11   5.5  0.421108
         12   6.0  0.957890
         13   6.5  0.533165
         14   7.0  0.691877
         15   7.5  0.315516
         16   8.0  0.686501
         17   8.5  0.834626
         18   9.0  0.018288
         19   9.5  0.750144
```

If need remove first level of `Multiindex`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['sample_1',:], ['Time','I']].reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
    Time         I
0    0.0  0.800745
1    0.5  0.968262
2    1.0  0.313424
3    1.5  0.692323
4    2.0  0.876389
5    2.5  0.894607
6    3.0  0.085044
7    3.5  0.039055
8    4.0  0.169830
9    4.5  0.878143
10   5.0  0.098347
11   5.5  0.421108
12   6.0  0.957890
13   6.5  0.533165
14   7.0  0.691877
15   7.5  0.315516
16   8.0  0.686501
17   8.5  0.834626
18   9.0  0.018288
19   9.5  0.750144
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this was exactly what I was searching for. But, considering I have concat the dataframes into a new one 'df', how can I print, for instance, the columns 'Time' and 'I' only from the sample_1?

Comment: Thank you for accepting. I want ask it you. Give me a sec, I add it to answer.

Comment: Thank you. That was great. I think that `df.loc['sample_1'][['Time', 'I']]` does also work.